# Unable to find/use named range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a simple automated invoicing sheet (on Excel 16.35, apparently). For now, I have a single sheet containing all the business info of clients. I've converted this sheet into a table (to handle dynamic requirements later) and struggling to pull the names of clients into a data validation field in another sheet.

Here's what the named range looks like in the original sheet (please note that the rest of the names are table names):

[image]

However, using this in another sheet seems impossible:

[image]

Hitting Ctrl+F3 (actually, Cmd+F3 since I'm on Mac) doesn't open the Name Manager or anything. I've also tried to get clever and use combinations like `=client_info!ClientNames` when I get the error `This type of reference cannot be used in a Data Validation format`. Using just `ClientNames` or `ClientInfoTable[ClientNames]`, of course, makes the dumb decision of using the text literally as the one and only value in the validation list.

I also read about scopes of named ranges but I have no idea how to change scopes here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a less-than-ideal solution for this. Turns out I don't need named ranges as long as I don't change the table and column names. Setting the data validation source as `=INDIRECT("ClientsInfoTable[Name]")` seems to do the trick.

Hopefully, this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to comment, hence making a post...

It is possible that the scope of the 'defined name' is set to `Sheet` instead of `Workbook`.

[image: Name Manager Edit Name]

You can delete the name and redefine the same with scope now set to Workbook.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I don't see any option for scope, and I mentioned it in my post. If you check my screenshots, you'll see that there is no control for scopes. Maybe it's the blessing of my Mac (Catalina).